# How do I keep all the letters from a string BEFORE a specific character in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Sup coder,

I'm having trouble finding a way to insert into a variable the `suffix-class` of an `option` in a `select` that is needed to hiden:

```
<option class="filteroption1 at-show" value="at-pei">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE East New Brunswick/P.E.I.]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 at-show" value="at-nflnd">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE Newfoundland]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 at-show" value="at-nova">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE Nova Scotia]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 at-show" value="at-nflnd">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE West New Brunswick]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 for-show" value="for-hk">
  Hong Kong
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 for-show" value="for-int">
  International
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 ont-show" value="ont-dur">
  Durham / Northumberland
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 ont-show" value="ont-ham">
  Hamilton
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 ont-show" value="ont-lond">
  London & District
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 ont-show" value="ont-ncapsel">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE National Capital Section]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 ont-show" value="ont-nbay">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE North Bay]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 ont-show" value="ont-nwo">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE Northwestern Ontario]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 ont-show" value="ont-tor">
  Toronto
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 prairie-show" value="prairie-man">
  Manitoba
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 prairie-show" value="prairie-sask">
  Saskatoon
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 prairie-show" value="prairie-man">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE South Saskatchewan (Interim)]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 qc-show" value="qc-mtl">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE Montreal]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 qc-show" value="qc-qc">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE Quebec]
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 qc-show" value="qc-sher">
  Sherbrooke
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 west-show" value="west-calg">
  Calgary
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 west-show" value="west-edm">
  Edmonton
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 west-show" value="west-van">
  Vancouver
</option>
<option class="filteroption1 west-show" value="west-vanIsl">
  [LOAD TRANSLATE Vancouver Island]
</option>
```

E.G. Need to check if a string starts with `ont` or `prairie`. I understand that it is the same principle as a `substring`, but its the `opposite`. I want to know how I can easily (yes easily, even in Pure Vanilla JS) only keep the part of a string before the character `-`.

Thanks for all your replies, every answer is a great one! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest one I can think of is just splitting the string on `-` and getting the first element of the array:

```js
const testString = 'This is a test-This should not show up'
console.log(testString.split('-')[0])
```

EDIT: If you're looking to apply this to multiple words in a string, Regex is the way to go.

```js
const stringTest = 'this-atasd is a test-aasodma to remove-slkdfmnlksdf suffixes-asuindkajsd'
const processedString = stringTest.replace(/-(?=.*)\w+/gi, '')
console.log(processedString)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you:

> Need to check if a string starts with ont or prairie.

Then you can simply use `RegExp.test()` to test precisely that:

```js
let rx = RegExp(/^(prairie-|ont-)/)  // start with prairie- or ont-

console.log(rx.test("prairie-man"))         // true
console.log(rx.test("ont-nbay"))            // true
console.log(rx.test("SomeOtherString"))     // false
console.log(rx.test("SomeOtherString-ont-")) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to extract a portion of a string before a certain character.

One approach is to split the string on that character and return the first part:

```js
function splitAndReturn(str, c) {
  return str.split(c)[0];
}

console.log(
  splitAndReturn('abcd', 'c') // 'ab'
)
```

Another option is to use a regular expression to match "everything before a character":

```js
function matchEverythingBeforeChar(str, c) {
  return str.match(new RegExp(`(.+)${c}`))[1]
}

console.log(
  matchEverythingBeforeChar('abcd', 'c') // 'ab'
)
```

Another option (probably best as a learning exercise) is to implement the functionality yourself with a loop. The loop will iterate through every character accumulating them until it finds the character you're looking for and then return the accumulation:

```js
function loopAndFind(str, c) {
  let acc = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === c) {
      return acc;
    }
    acc += str[i];
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(
  loopAndFind('abcd', 'c') // 'ab'
)
```

JavaScript also provides us with shortcut methods to achieve this accumulation functionality:

```js
function loopAndFindWithNativeMethods(str, c) {
  return str.substring(0, str.indexOf(c))
}

console.log(
  loopAndFindWithNativeMethods('abcd', 'c') // 'ab'
)
```